# Change text of Button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I am trying to Change the text of Button when opening the scene in Unity. I tried different methods to change the text of Button.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class script : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button b1;
    public TMP_Text b1text;


    void Start()
    {
        GameObject b1object = (GameObject)Instantiate(b1);
        b1text = b1object.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>(true);
        btnValue();
    }

    public void btnValue()
    {
        b1text.text = "sdfa";
    }

}
```

Comment: are you trying to create dynamic buttons?

Comment: What exactly didn't work / behave different from what you expected?

Comment: It gave me error of this: Assets/Scripts/script.cs(15,43): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.UI.Button' to `UnityEngine.GameObject'

Comment: yes it will give that error because of GameObject b1object = (GameObject)Instantiate(b1);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
   public Button b1;
public TextMeshProUGUI b1text;


void Start()
{
    b1text = b1.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    btnValue();
}

public void btnValue()
{
    b1text.text = "sdfa";
}
```

or you could just create a

> public TextMeshProUGUI txt;

drag the textmeshpro text in the inspector and change the text.

> ```
>     txt.text = "sdfa";
> ```

Comment: what did you use for b1object?

Comment: TextMeshProUGUI class reference not working anymore.https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmeshprougui-class-reference-not-working-anymore.541571/

Comment: did you put the namespace . using TMPro;   ? You are using textmeshPro right ?

Comment: Yes, I put the namespace and am using Textmeshpro for android.

Comment: I want to change the text of the button.

Comment: I changed my code to:using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class script : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button b1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b1text;


    void Start()
    {
        GameObject b1object = Instantiate(b1.gameObject);
        b1text = b1object.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        btnValue();
    }

    public void btnValue()
    {
        
        b1text.text = "sdfa";
     
    }

}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182728/discussion-between-ak-pasaf-and-joel64).